# Create file based database on startup of a .NET program

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, sqlite

I'm using the Entity Framework in a small command line application.
Now I want to deploy this program - and I want it to create a small local file based sql database besides the program, if it doesn't exist (first start).

What is the best practice for such a simple project? SQLLite, SQL Server Compact Edition? I don't want to create the database manually from within Visual Studio - since the later users of the program wouldn't be able to do the same. Also there should be not setup or "manually setup of a database" for the user later.

Or do I have to deploy a simple, empty database file with the application itself? But how specify I this database in the connection string during development?

Thanks

Konrad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689041/sqlite-deployment-for-net-application

Answer (score 0):

It firgured out, that SQL Server Compact Edition was the best solution.