# Is there a way to install sqlite in a wpf project without to size of the file too heavy?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I am developing a WPF application using sqlite, but I noticed that when I installed sqlite via nuget the size of the project increases almost 60 MB, is this right? Is there another way to do this so that the project is not so heavy?
I want the application to serve both 32x and 64x.

Comment: Just include the necessary drivers you need manually and it should not be more than 1MB or even less.

Comment: Juergen, thakns you. I tried that but it did not work. I don't kwon if I follow the right steps because I could not load the interop and consequently when I compliled it throws a error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite deployment for .net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689041/sqlite-deployment-for-net-application)

Comment: dymanoid, sorry I didn´t understand. What did you mean?