# How can I built a standalone windows desktop application ,where I don't need to install any server additionally on client's machine?

Tags: sql, wpf, sqlite, mvvm, desktop-application

I am developing desktop app using wpf mvvm,however I am confused as to how should I proceed with developing standalone application using sqlite,sql server compact etc

Comment: You could also consider SQL Azure - a SQL database in the cloud that you can connect to remotely.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a database (really need a database), I suggest using Entity Framework using the code first approach.  This can create a local database for the application w/o the need of a database server.

However, strongly consider if you could just use files in the file system.  It is amazing how much you can load into memory and if you want this to run on client machine, you likely don't have so much data that you can't just load the data into memory.

Comment: Thanks @geoff , can you share any link which will help me understand your approach in detail?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Compact [requires a separate installation step with administrative credentials](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190958.aspx).

SQLite is a library that can be compiled directly into the application.
In the case of .NET, it is a part of the [System.Data.SQLite package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite), so it is automatically available when your application is shipped with this package (see [SQLite deployment for .net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689041/sqlite-deployment-for-net-application)).