# Checklist when deploying SQLite with .NET application

Tags: .net, sqlite, deployment, clickonce

I need to deploy SQLite file with WPF application.

- Deployment technique is *ClickOnce*.
- *Entity Framework* is included to work with the database.

I'd like to have a shortlist what must be considered when deploying the application that includes a SQLite database file in it.

So far, I have referenced and set **Copy Local to True** for:

- System.Data.SQLite
- System.Data.SQLite.Linq

.and I have two interops where Copy to Output Directory I left to be the default **Copy Always**

- SQLite.Interop.dll (x86)
- SQLite.Interop.dll (x64)

In the app.config file I have:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <MyApp.MySettings>
       <setting name="connStrSQLite" serializeAs="String">
           <value>data source="C:\MyFolder\MySQLiteFile.sqlite3"</value>
       </setting>
    </MyApp.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

and

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.ORM.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Model.ORM.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.ORM.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string='data source=&quot;C:\MyFolder\MySQLiteFile.sqlite3&quot;'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I suppose in the app.config the paths are not working on deployed application since they are referring to my local folder now.
**How to modify them**?

Then, I checked for example from here [SQLite deployment for .net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689041/sqlite-deployment-for-net-application) that the following should be added to app.config file.

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Anything else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to deploy sqlite with .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728175/how-to-deploy-sqlite-with-net)

Comment: So how to automatically include those interops? The only answer doesn't seem to address the Q though is accepted. @Dimi This is not a duplicate as it deals with other deployment method.

Comment: [The linked approach for ClickOnce](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23896952/673826) seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding your connection string - for ClickOnce installation you should use |DataDirectory| substitution instead of full path - runtime will automatically convert this into proper local path:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|Mydb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```